# Use python keyword as model field in peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, reserved-words, peewee

I am building an ORM for an *existing* database with peewee in python3.

Now I face the problem in one table, that there is a column named `import`, which i must introduce as a class' attribute. This, of course does not work that simple because it is a keyword in the python language. Is there a way to change the name of a field in another way? I cannot change the column's name since it will create massive side-effects on other systems.

Comment: You can rename the class attribute to something else (like `import_`) and pass in `db_column='import'` into the field.

Comment: Perfect. Now I even found it in the official documentation. I must have skipped that in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `db_column` attribute:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    import_ = CharField(db_column='import')
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create a class attribute with name `import`. The downside is that you always have to access it programmatically:

```
In [1]: class Test(object):
   ...:     locals()['import'] = 1
   ...:     

In [2]: getattr(Test, 'import')
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: setattr(Test, 'import', 2)

In [4]: getattr(Test, 'import')
Out[4]: 2
```

You could hide the accesses to `getattr` and `setattr` using a custom metaclass for this class and adding a `@property` named `import_` that will modify the value of `import`. So you can use `import_` in your python code, and the `import` attribute will be syncrhonized automatically.

Alternatively you can simply use a metaclass that defines a custom `__getattr__` that will handle the `import` attribute in any way you want.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But in my case, @Bleder's  solution seems more feasible. Nonetheless this is good to know!